# Windows 8.1 Task Manager not showing graphs at all

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager

When I'm choosing *Performance* tab in *Task Manager* of *Windows 8.1* it appears to be blank.

[image]

[image]

Running as administrator and restarting *Taskmgr.exe* doesn't seem to help.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: can you please post a picture of how Taskmgr currently looks?

Comment: @magicandre1981 this is how it looks like: [Example 1](http://s30.postimg.org/cow86mazl/problem.png). Some menu items are disabled: [Example 2](http://s24.postimg.org/tqcatdoyd/problem1.png)

Comment: maybe the perf counters are damaged. try to register them again: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956/en-us

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your advice. I guess it would help. however, i've been experiencing some other critical bugs (copy-paste not working, some software not opening, ms visual studio crashes and so on) since latest updates of win8.1 so I decided to reset my PC to factory settings.

Comment: ok, post that as answer and mark it as answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two options currently available as far as I know:

1. try to [refresh, reset or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) (in my case reset worked i.e *removing everything and reinstalling Windows*)
2. or [manually rebuild Performance Counter Library values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956/en-us)